# sum of JTable column values and sum display in last row

Tags: java

I have 28 columns, Amount is one of them and one total button. so when I pressed total button  want to show sum of Amount column in last row. I used DefaultTableModel and want to display sum of amount below the amount columnonly
    I tried this code -

```
totalbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            Object source = ae.getSource();

            if (source == totalbtn) 
            { 
                double total = 0.0;
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"","" ,new Integer(1), "", new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),"",new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0),new Double(0.0)});
                for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount()-1 ; i++)
                {
                    double Amount = (double) model.getValueAt(i, 5);
                    total = Amount+total;

                }    
                    model.setValueAt(total,model.getRowCount()-1,5);
              //      model.setValueAt(total,i,5);
                    System.out.println("total is"+total);







            }
        }


    });
```

Comment: First, What is the question ? And this is a long array for a 8column array, are you sure of that ? PS : ` if (source == total)` was strange for me, since you have a `double total ` later. you should rename it to `totalBtn` to be more understandable

Comment: Also fix the indentation, the current one is frightnening.

Comment: I fixed it. how I achieve solution for it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - Please enhance the code in your quiestion do be3 a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Move `double total = 0;` outside of the loop. But with some explanation it would have be simpler to notice.

Comment: @Timothy trucle, I'll take care from next question

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){
    double total = 0; //#########3
    double Amount = (double) model.getValueAt(i, 5);
    total = Amount+total;
    model.setValueAt(total,i,5);
    System.out.println("total is"+total);
}
```

You can see you are declaring your total value for each row. So you will erase it and end up with the last value in your new row.

```
double total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){
     .. .
}
```

Also, since you add a row, you should not read the last value since this is the `total` one, you would end up with a `total *2` result. So change the condition like :

```
for(int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount() -1 ; i++){ //To skip the `total` row
```

Then, since I notice this only now, you need to set the value after you have calculate `total`. After the loop.

```
for(){ ... }
model.setValueAt(total,model.getRowCount() - 1 ,5);
```

Comment: thank you, but it not works...in last row i got 0, here I paste my new code

Comment: @Vsal my bad, didn't write everything I had in mind. Same an the declaration, you are setting the value in the loop (for each value), don't need that. Just calculate `total` in the loop then after the loop set the value of the last row.

Comment: @AxelH...it not works here,i put 2 in first row of amount column, then 4 in second row,so i got 2 in third row....not able to recognize problem, here i paste my new code

Comment: @Vsal you need to debug yourself, since this only see the first row, check the value of `model.getRowCount()` between the loop and the addRow. See if it is notified that there is one more row, if not, just remove the "-1" but this is unlikely.